# How to find angle of point from x-axis independant of quadrant?

Tags: java, math, trigonometry, cartesian-coordinates

Given a point (x,y), how do I calculate the angle from the x-axis?

```
        |    . <- (x,y)
        |   /
        |  /
        | /
        |/
--------+---------
        |
        |
```

Currently I have

```
Math.atan(y/x) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

However, this does not represent all the coordinates properly. Here are the results for this in each of the quadrants (counterclockwise).

```
Quadrant 1: 0 -> -90
Quadrant 2: 90 -> 0
Quadrant 3: 0 -> -90
Quadrant 4: 90 -> 0
```

How can I write a statement that will give me the angle from the x-axis of any point such that the results for the quadrants look like this.

```
Quadrant 1: 0 -> 90
Quadrant 2: 90 -> 180
Quadrant 3: 180 -> 270
Quadrant 4: 270 -> 360
```

Basically how do I make this work in all four quadrants?

Comment: I don't believe you ;) (http://ideone.com/fUsZT5)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Wat... let me check my code...

Comment: int direction = (int) (180 * Math.atan((player_y+Mouse.getY()-height)/(player_x-Mouse.getX()))/Math.PI);

This is my full code. I checked the 2 parameters and they perform like I describe above...

Comment: Got it. Math.atan() does not function quite as well as Math.atan2() :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `atan`. It's just that `atan2` is usually much easier since you don't have to take care of these kinds of special cases.

Comment: atan2() automatically takes care of quadrants for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Math.atan2()` because it returns a value from 0->180 in the first two quadrants and -180->0 in the last 2.

Comment: I don't get it. In your question you claimed that `Math.atan2` does not return the correct result. Now your answer is to use `Math.atan2` ... ?